# Passar arquivos por ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou criando o formulário de registro de produtos de um site, e nele, todos os formulários são submetidos por ajax à uma api. O problema é que nesse formulário em específico eu preciso enviar imagens para o servidor. Estou tentando utilizar o objeto FormData para o envio, mas sem sucesso. Segue o código javascript que eu estou utilizando:

```
$("#formProduto").submit((e) => {
    var formProduto = document.getElementById('formProduto');
    var formData = new FormData(formProduto);
    $.ajax("/admin/produto/api", {
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        success: (data) => {
            //Sucesso
        }
    }
    return e.preventDefault();
});
```

Utilizando `data: $("#formProduto").serialize()` (sem o arquivo, claro) o ajax funciona normalmente, quando eu troco pelo código acima ele apenas ignora o `e.preventDefault();` e submita o form pra própria página.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro verifique se seu formulário tem o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` que permite o envio de arquivos, depois mude seu código para algo como:

```
var fData = new FormData($('#formProduto')[0]);
$.ajax({
  url : "/admin/produto/api",
  dataType: 'json',
  processData: false,
  data: fData,
  type: 'POST',
  contentType: false,
  success : function() {
    console.log("success", success);        
  },
  complete: function() {
    console.log("complete", complete);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("error", error);        
  }
});
```

Adicionando as opções `processData: false` e `contentType: false`

Comment: Mesmo utilizando ajax para o envio do formulário eu preciso setar o enctype?

Comment: As informações do formulário não estão chegando na server-side (NodeJS/Express).

Comment: Tinha feito com PHP, com node pode ser que seja de uma forma diferente. Sem o enctype os campos de arquivo não são enviados junto os outros campos. Submeta a form é veja os campos que estão sendo passados na requisição, se tiver usando Chrome vê na aba Network.

Comment: O módulo que eu estou utilizando não suporta o envio de arquivos, vou ter que utilizar outro pra conseguir pegar as informações, alterar o meu backend inteiro ahhhhh, mas vlw ai cara

Comment: Blz, boa sorte com a refatoração.